# SD card protocol over Ethernet

Tags: fpga, sd-card, ethernet

I am working on a project which one of its requirements is to control SD card(read and write data) over Ethernet, eventually i need to transfer SD card traffic from slave side (SD card slot) to master side(SD core) and vise versa, over Ethernet.
In the master side i have SD card controller (implemented on micro-controller) and FPGA which response to get the data from the micro-controller,pack it and transmit it to the slave side over Ethernet.
In the slave side i have FPGA which response to get the Ethernet frame,parse it and pass the commands and data to the SD card slot.
my problem is the busy line in the micro-controller SD core which expect to get busy realize by limited timeout.
i am suspect that the Ethernet transfer latency plus the slave side latency will fail down the micro controller SD core.( maybe this will considered as SD card retrieving)

as i understood , the option of implement the file system layer of the SD card controller in the slave FPGA is a bit complicated.

does someone has a relevant experience and can share with me some advice's?

Comment: "In the slave side i have FPGA ...to get the Ethernet frame,parse it " I doubt you have written a complete Ethernet packet handler in HDL code, so I assume you have a processor. In which case you can use the processor to write to the SD-card. As that is also a protocol too complex to write in HDL. You can do the low level card access (e.g. SPI) in HDL though.

Comment: Can't you configure the timeout in SD core?

Answer (score 0):

You need a file server or storage protocol.

If the file system runs on the server and the client uses file level access you need an appropriate file system protocol like NFS, SMB, or simply FTP or TFTP.

You can also use block level access between client and server (file system running on client) with a block storage protocol like iSCSI, HyperSCSI, ATA over Ethernet or similar - the latter is probably the easiest to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the protocol between master side and slave side to be higher level, e.g., readBlock() and writeBlock(), then only the slave side needs to meet SD card timing requirements.